# character frequency program does not work

Tags: arrays, floating-point, character

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        String input = new Scanner( new File("characterfreq.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        char[] character = input.toCharArray();
        int size = character.length;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        float count = 0;

        for (i=0; i < size; ++i) {
            count = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                if (j < i && character[i] == character[j]) {
                    break;
                }
                if (character[j] == character[i]) 
                    count++;
            }
            if (j == size-1) {
                System.out.println(character[i]+" is present "+count/size+" times");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please can you help me, when i run the code nothing happens, i had the code running fine at one point, i added another line and messed it up and now i cant figure out what i did wrong

Comment: What do you want to do? print just the frequency? if so why are you printing `count/size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed an opening bracket in your code at the second `if` construct in your for loop, insert the bracket and it should work:

```
if (character[j] == character[i]) {
    count++;
}
```

also change your print statement to print only the `count`, and not `count/size` if you want the actual frequency.